# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/SchemaRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting a NoClassDefFound error when trying to run Spark. I cannot figure out the reason behind this. Please help.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/spark/sql/SchemaRDD
>         at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
>         at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
>         at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
>         at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:659)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
>         at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD
>         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>         ... 10 more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NOClassDefFound error while running a simple java program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619868/noclassdeffound-error-while-running-a-simple-java-program)

Comment: Check if that class is in your working directory.

Answer (score 2):

[NoClassDefFoundError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) means Java couldn't find the Class it was looking for. That normally means:

1. You defined wrongly the classpath.
2. Java is finding and using the wrong version of the jar (probably because of Maven dependency hell).

Solution for 1 is to check the classpath: make sure you are including the jar that defines `org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD`.

Solution for 2 is to check if you have a Maven dependency that depends (transitively) on an older version of the resource that defines that class.